# Insert missing dates into existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a query that finds missing dates from a table.

The query is:

```
;WITH NullGaps AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ChannelName, ReadingDate) AS ID,
        SerialNumber, ReadingDate, ChannelName, uid
    FROM 
        [UriData]   
)   
SELECT 
    (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, g1.ReadingDate , g2.ReadingDate) / 15) -1 AS 'MissingCount',
    g1.ReadingDate AS 'FromDate', g2.ReadingDate AS 'ToDate'                
FROM 
    NullGaps g1
INNER JOIN 
    NullGaps g2 ON g1.ID = (g2.ID - 1)
WHERE 
    DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, g1.ReadingDate) < g2.ReadingDate
```

The output is:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| MissingCount |      FromDate         |      ToDate         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|    2         |  2018-09-20 14:30:00  | 2018-09-20 15:15:00 |
|    1         |  2018-09-20 15:30:00  | 2018-09-20 16:00:00 |
|    1         |  2018-09-20 20:30:00  | 2018-09-20 21:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

The output is the number of datetimes that are missing from the FromDate to the ToDate (which both exist). For example, in the first row of the output (above), the times I want to create and insert will be `'2018-09-20 14:45:00'` and `'2018-09-20 15:00:00'` (they are all 15-minute intervals)

I need to understand, how I now create the new dates and insert them into an existing table. I can create one date, but I can't create dates where there are multiple missing values between two times.

TIA

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b0d24)

Comment: This type of query comes up reasonably often, have you not found any other SO answers that help out?

Comment: Some recommend keeping a date timetable, as some of the devices run by the second, it would be monstrous and 250 channels a device, I would be getting into trillions of rows, others suggest a UNION, but typing the date ranges. I want something more dynamic. I am learning SQL at the mo' and struggle with some of the concepts.

Comment: You create a datetime table that meets your interval needs. 15 minute intervals is 96 records a day- hardly monstrous. Techniques exist to generate the date range on the fly, and you then join your sparse data onto your generated "guaranteed to have all the intervals" data. On the fly generation can be more expensive than just keeping a datetime or numbers table kicking around, depends how often and how you use it. What is unarguable though is that it comes up on here time and again so there will be some good ref material out there for a variety of techniques

Comment: @Caius Thanks for that, some things I saw on here said to create every possible date. I will also take a look at these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also want to find the missing datetimes at the start and the end of a date?

Then comparing to generated datetimes should be a valiable method.

Such dates can be generated via a Recursive CTE.

Then you can join your data to the Recursive CTE and select those that are missing.
Or use a `NOT EXISTS`.

For example:

```
WITH RCTE AS
(
  select [SerialNumber], [ChannelName], 0 as Lvl, cast(cast([ReadingDate] as date) as datetime) as ReadingDate
  from [UriData]
  group by SerialNumber, [ChannelName], cast([ReadingDate] as date)

  union all

  select [SerialNumber], [ChannelName], Lvl + 1, DATEADD(MINUTE,15,[ReadingDate])
  from RCTE
  where cast([ReadingDate] as date) = cast(DATEADD(MINUTE,15,[ReadingDate]) as date)
)
SELECT [SerialNumber], [ChannelName], [ReadingDate] AS FromDate
FROM RCTE r
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  select 1
  from [UriData] t
  where t.[SerialNumber] = r.[SerialNumber]
    and t.[ChannelName] = r.[ChannelName]
    and t.[ReadingDate] = r.[ReadingDate]
);
```

A test can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d0c4f/3/0)

And here's another query that takes a different approuch :

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT SerialNumber, ChannelName, ReadingDate,
   LAG(ReadingDate) OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber, ChannelName ORDER BY ReadingDate) AS prevReadingDate
  FROM [UriData] 
)
, RCTE AS
(
  select SerialNumber, ChannelName, 0 as Lvl, 
   prevReadingDate AS ReadingDate, 
   prevReadingDate AS MinReadingDate,
   ReadingDate AS MaxReadingDate
  from CTE
  where DATEDIFF(MINUTE, prevReadingDate, ReadingDate) > 15

  union all

  select SerialNumber, ChannelName, Lvl + 1, 
   DATEADD(MINUTE,15,ReadingDate),
   MinReadingDate,
   MaxReadingDate
  from RCTE
  where ReadingDate < DATEADD(MINUTE,-15,MaxReadingDate)
)
select SerialNumber, ChannelName, 
 ReadingDate AS FromDate, 
 DATEADD(MINUTE,15,ReadingDate) AS ToDate, 
 dense_rank() over (partition by SerialNumber, ChannelName order by MinReadingDate) as GapRank,
 (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MinReadingDate, MaxReadingDate) / 15)  AS TotalMissingQuarterGaps
from RCTE
where Lvl > 0 AND MinReadingDate < MaxReadingDate
ORDER BY SerialNumber, ChannelName, MinReadingDate;
```

You can test that one [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d0c4f/17/0)

Comment: It works well, but I think I need to add a min and max date, as it is backfilling the entire day from the first date and the last date, so I have times I don't want. I ran it on a larger dataset and it has added dates that shouldn't exist. Do I need add to another union so I can set the start and end dates (this may differ with different devices and there are thousands of devices)...

Comment: I shoud also say, I have tried adding MIN(Date) to the query but I get an error: GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'RCTE'.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin Well, this method basically finds the gap datetimes per 15 minutes. You could change the select in the outer query by `SELECT [SerialNumber], [ChannelName], [ReadingDate] AS FromDate, DATEADD(MINUTE,15,[ReadingDate]) AS ToDate`.  But I'm not sure that's what you want?

Comment: That's kind of it... The data may start at 14:15 on a given day and end at 16:15 on another day, it should start and finish from those datetimes, at the mo' it's backfilling and forward filling to midnight as well as finding the missing data. Unfortunately, every device has a different start DateTime.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin Check out the new query that was just included.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your query for calculating missing values.  Your question doesn't have sample data or explain the logic.  I'm pretty sure that `lag()` would be much simpler.

But given your query (or any other), one method to expand out the data is to use a recursive CTE:

```
with missing as (<your query here>)
     cte as (
      select dateadd(minute, 15, fromdate) as dte, missingcount - 1 as missingcount
      from missing
      union all
      select dateadd(minute, 15, dte), missingcount - 1
      from cte
      where missingcount > 0
     )
select *
from cte;
```

If you have more than 100 missing times in one row, then add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to the end of the query.

Comment: The query fetches the two dates that have time missing between them, the MissingCount tells me how many intervals are missing, between those two times. It also gives me the options to pick specific channels and devices and dates. I can then set a processed flag and a null flag if required (once I understand how to do it.)

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin . . . What I don't understand is why you are not using `lag()`.  That is not germaine to your question, if your query is working.  That part seems more complicated than necessary, but is not relevant to the question.

Comment: I've been learning SQL and all of the training I have done have never mentioned lag and told me to do it as shown. I will check out Lag and see if I can get my solution. Thanks for pointing me that way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information shared with me, I did the following which does what I need.

The first part is to find the date ranges that are missing by finding the from and to dates that have missing dates between them, then insert them into a table for auditing, but it will hold the missing dates I am looking for:

```
;WITH NullGaps AS(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ChannelName, ReadingDate) AS ID,SerialNumber, ReadingDate, ChannelName, uid
        FROM [Staging].[UriData]
    ) 
        INSERT INTO [Staging].[MissingDates]
        SELECT (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, g1.ReadingDate , g2.ReadingDate) / 15) -1 AS 'MissingCount', 
                g1.ChannelName, 
                g1.SerialNumber,
                g1.ReadingDate AS FromDate,
                g2.ReadingDate AS ToDate              
        FROM NullGaps g1
            INNER JOIN NullGaps g2 
            ON g1.ID = (g2.ID - 1)
        WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, g1.ReadingDate) < g2.ReadingDate 
            AND g1.ChannelName IN (SELECT ChannelName FROM staging.ActiveChannels) 
            AND NOT EXISTS(
                    SELECT 1 FROM [Staging].[MissingDates] m 
                    WHERE m.Channel = g1.ChannelName
                        AND m.Serial = g1.SerialNumber
                        AND m.FromDate = g1.ReadingDate
                        AND m.ToDate = g2.ReadingDate
            )
```

Now that I have the ranges to look for, I can now create the missing dates and insert them into the table that holds real data.

```
;WITH MissingDateTime AS(
            SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, FromDate) AS dte, MissingCount -1 AS MissingCount, Serial, Channel
                FROM [Staging].[MissingDates]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, dte), MissingCount - 1, Serial, Channel
                FROM MissingDateTime
                WHERE MissingCount > 0
        ) -- END CTE

        INSERT INTO [Staging].[UriData]
        SELECT NEWID(), Serial, Channel, '999', '0', dte, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 0,1,0 FROM MissingDateTime m
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 FROM [Staging].[UriData] u
                WHERE u.ChannelName = m.Channel
                AND u.SerialNumber = m.Serial
                AND u.ReadingDate = m.dte
            ) -- END SELECT
```

I am sure you can offer improvements to this. This solution finds only the missing dates and allows me to back fill my data table with only the missing dates. I can also change the intervals later should other devices need to be used for different intervals. I have put the queries in two sperarate SPROC's so I can control both apects, being: one for auditing and one for back filling.